# 2 proofs on consistency

Tags: proof-verification, logic

Could anyone check if my proof for the following is correct please? In particular, I am not feeling very comfortable about my inference from $Γ \vdash φ$ to $Γ ∪ \{¬φ\} \vdash φ$.

> Let $Γ$ be a set of formulas and $φ$ a formula.
>
> a). $Γ ∪ \{¬φ\}$ is inconsistent if and only if $Γ \vdash φ$.
>
> b). Suppose that $Γ$ is consistent and $Γ \vdash φ$. Then $Γ∪ \{φ\}$ is consistent.

a). The $\rightarrow$ has already been provided in the book, so I will only prove $\leftarrow$.

Suppose $Γ \vdash φ$. We need to prove that $Γ ∪ \{¬φ\} \vdash \phi$ and $Γ ∪ \{¬φ\} \vdash \lnot\phi$.

Since $Γ \vdash φ$, and $Γ$ is a member of the broader set of assumptions $Γ ∪ \{¬φ\}$, that must mean there is also a proof from this broader set to $φ$, ie. $Γ ∪ \{¬φ\} \vdash φ$.

$\lnot φ$ is itself already a member of the set of assumption $Γ ∪ \{¬φ\}$, so $Γ ∪ \{¬φ\} \vdash \lnot φ$.

Since from $Γ ∪ \{¬φ\}$ one can derive both $\lnot φ$ and $φ$, this set is inconsistent.

b). Suppose that $Γ$ is consistent and $Γ \vdash φ$. If $Γ∪ \{φ\}$ is not consistent, then that means $Γ∪ \{φ\} \vdash\psi $ and $Γ∪ \{φ\} \vdash \lnot\psi $. $\{φ\}$ on its own cannot derive $\lnot φ$, so IF this is possible it must be from $Γ$.

But we know that $Γ$ is consistent and $Γ \vdash φ$, so it is impossible for $Γ \vdash \lnot φ$ as well. So to conclude it is impossible for $Γ∪ \{φ\} \vdash \lnot\psi $ and hence $Γ∪ \{φ\}$ is consistent.

Comment: If $\Gamma_0\subseteq \Gamma_1$ then any proof from $\Gamma_0$ is also a proof from $\Gamma_1$ (there's no requirement that *all* the axioms be used, after all). So your inference is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could anyone check if my proof for the following is correct please?

It reads clear and is correct.  It is a good proof.

> In particular, I am not feeling very comfortable about my inference from $Γ \vdash φ$ to $Γ ∪ \{¬φ\} \vdash φ$.

If you can derive $\varphi$ from (some of the) assumptions in set $\Gamma$, then you can derive $\varphi$ from (some of the) assumptions in *any superset* of $\Gamma$; including inconsistent ones.

Comment: @NoahSchweber and Graham: thank you for your comments, really appreciate it!